# Exporting vector layer with symbology using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, export, kml, vector-layer

I want to export vector layer with symbology on PyQGIS. So, like the code below, I try export to *.kml* with `symbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology`.

But It couldn't export with symbology.
Is there any good solutions?

```py
symbol = layer.renderer().symbol()

symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,5,0))

symbol.setSize(6)
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setShape(QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerBase.Arrow)
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))

layer.triggerRepaint()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, path, "UTF-8", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326), 'KML', symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology)
```